# Find point between two intervals which equals the average value.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Find the point in the interval [5,9] at which the function $f(x)=17e^{3x}$ equals its average value on that interval.

So I've got my function as follows $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{17}{3}(e^{27}-e^{15})$
So I've simplify it to $\frac{17e^{12}}{12}$

Now I believe I have to solve for $c$ so I've replace $x$ in my original function with $c$ so it looks like $17e^{3c}=\frac{17e^{12}}{12}$

So how would I go on from here, or am I doing the whole thing wrong.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average value is indeed $\frac{1}{12}(17)(e^{27}-e^{15})$. It does not simplify in a very useful way, though you may want to write it as
$$\frac{1}{12}(e^{15})(e^{12}-1).$$
Now you want to solve the equation
$$17e^{3c}=\frac{1}{12}(17)(e^{15})(e^{12}-1).$$
We might as well cancel the $17$'s. After that, take the logarithm of both sides. 
The logarithm can be written as $15+\ln(e^{12}-1)-\ln(12)$. Divide by $3$ to get $c$.

Comment: Why is it $(17)(e^{27}-e^{15})/4$ and not $(17)(e^{27}-e^{15})/2$?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $3$ in the denominator from the integration.

Comment: $\int_a^b 17e^{3x}\,dx=\left[\frac{17}{3}e^{3x}\right]_a^b$. This is where the $\frac13$ comes from - the integration; not just looking at endpoints. Or rather, yes looking at endpoints on the antiderivative.

Comment: I suspect @GTXOC has the same comment as me, but maybe meant $12$ in the denominator not $2$? Not sure where $2$ would come from.

Comment: Agree, GTX OC probably was objecting to my forgetting about the $3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't know how you did it, but thank you so much!!! This problem was kicking my ass.

Comment: You write that you do not know how I did it. Is there any place I can add detail? The first problem you had was that you simplified incorrectly, $e^{27}-e^{15}$ is not $e^{12}$ ($e^{27}$ **divided** by $e^{15}$ is $e^{12}$). After that, you are looking at the equation $e^{3c}=K$ where $K$ is a "known" somewhat complicated number. Take logs. You get $3c=\ln(K)$ and therefore $c=\frac{\ln(K)}{3}$.